# I wish to build a file transfer application in c#.........i have internet dongles on both ends(client/server). What ip addresses to use?

Tags: c#, tcp, file-transfer

I have tried making a tcp connection......didn't work.
when i try to ping the public address of the remote server i don't receive any data.
whatismyip.com and what is my ip(google search) gives me different public ips.
(which one to use?)

code for server :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public string Status = string.Empty;
    public Thread T = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Server is Running...";
        ThreadStart Ts = new ThreadStart(StartReceiving);
        T = new Thread(Ts);
        T.Start();


    }
    public void StartReceiving()
    {
        ReceiveTCP(29250);
    }


    public void ReceiveTCP(int portN)
    {
        TcpListener Listener = null;
        try
        {
            Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portN);
            Listener.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        byte[] RecData = new byte[BufferSize];
        int RecBytes;

        for (; ; )
        {
            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netstream = null;
            Status = string.Empty;
            try
            {


                string message = "Accept the Incoming File ";
                string caption = "Incoming Connection";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                DialogResult result;


                if (Listener.Pending())
                {
                    client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    netstream = client.GetStream();
                    Status = "Connected to a client\n";
                    result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);

                    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        string SaveFileName=string.Empty;
                        SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
                        DialogSave.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
                        DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
                        DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
                        DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
                        if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            SaveFileName = DialogSave.FileName;
                        if (SaveFileName != string.Empty)
                        {
                            int totalrecbytes = 0;
                            FileStream Fs = new FileStream(SaveFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                            while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                                totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                            }
                            Fs.Close();
                        }
                        netstream.Close();
                        client.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                //netstream.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        T.Abort();
        this.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple public IPs. Also, what do you mean this "didn't work"? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: what is my IP on google search gives me IPv6 address -> 2406:5600:17:aaa3:84c4:479:8266:3984,     , whatismyipaddress.com shows -> 116.203.73.76,     ipconfig says IPv6 address same as google search, IPv4 address -> 100.64.83.54............i am confused which one to connect to.

this code runs a TCP server which i try to connect to using client code using the IP address of this server.........but i fail to do so.

i can't even ping any of these addresses.